# CORS error while redirecting angular page from spring boot: header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors, preflight

I am developing an application with angular 6 as front end and spring boot as back end. Currently I am working with forgot password functionality :

1. Taking email id from angular and sending an email to the id.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/forgotPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> forgotPassword(@RequestParam("email") String recepientemail, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Optional<User> userlist = userRepository.findByEmail(recepientemail);
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
    if (userlist.isPresent()) {
        User u = userlist.get();
        u.setResetToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());       
           u.setResetTokenExpiry(simpleDateFormat.format(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 1)));
            u.setModifiedBy(u.getId());
            u.setModifiedDate(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
            userRepository.save(u);
            String appUrl = request.getScheme() + "://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getLocalPort();

            // Email message
            email.sendSimpleEmail(u.getEmail(), "DIS Password Reset Request",
                    "To reset your password, click the link below:\n" + appUrl + "/dis/resetPassword?resetToken="
                            + u.getResetToken());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new ResponseMessage("A password reset link has been sent to registered email address!"),
                    HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ResponseMessage("We didn't find an account for this e-mail address!"),
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }
```

2. By clicking on link spring boot will redirect to the angular's reset password page.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetPassword", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView displayResetPasswordPage(@RequestParam("resetToken") String token) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByResetToken(token);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        if (user.isPresent()) { // Token found in DB
            if (simpleDateFormat.parse(user.get().getResetTokenExpiry()).after(new Date())) {
                modelAndView.addObject("resetToken", token);
                modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:4200/reset-password");
            } else {
                modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Oops!  Your password reset link has expired.");
                modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:4200/forgot-password");
            }
        } else { // Token not found in DB
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Oops!  This is an invalid password reset link.");
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:4200/forgot-password");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

3. By entering the new password on reset page, angular will pass the reset token and new password to spring boot and then spring boot should redirect to login page after successful change of password.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processResetPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView setNewPassword(@RequestBody Map<String, String> requestParams, RedirectAttributes redir, HttpServletResponse response) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByResetToken(requestParams.get("resetToken"));
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        if (user.isPresent()) {
            User resetUser = user.get();
            resetUser.setPassword(encoder.encode(requestParams.get("password")));
            resetUser.setResetToken(null);
            resetUser.setResetTokenExpiry(null);
            resetUser.setModifiedBy(resetUser.getId());
            resetUser.setModifiedDate(simpleDateFormat.format(new Date()));
            userRepository.save(resetUser);
            //redir.addFlashAttribute("successMessage", "You have successfully reset your password. You may now login.");
            //modelAndView.addObject("successMessage", "You have successfully reset your password. You may now login.");
           modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:4200");
            return modelAndView;
        } else {
            modelAndView.addObject("errorMessage", "Oops!  This is an invalid password reset link.");
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:http://localhost:4200/forgot-password");
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Now the problem is, in second point spring boot is able to redirect the reset password page perfectly but in third point while redirecting to login page it is giving CORS error. Why?

Here is the screenshot of error [image: screenshot]

Edit:
Here is cross origin annotation

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dis")
public class AuthRestAPIs {....}
```

and here is the request header at network [image: request header]

Comment: I don't see an `@CrossOrigin` annotation anywhere, and you didn't show the HTTP headers from your network requests. As a note, passing `HttpServletRequest` is nearly always a sign that you are taking more trouble than is necessary. In this case, pass `UriComponentsBuilder` instead; you can use `MvcUriComponentsBuilder.relativeTo` to create the link you want in a much cleaner fashion.

Comment: @chrylis , Hey, I have update my question with `@CrossOrigin` and request header, please have a look and also, I am passing `HttpServletRequest` in `forgotPassword` method and that's working fine. Moreover, in `setNewPassword` method else part is working fine, it is perfectly redirect to forgot password page, so, i am confused that what's the problem with if part in the same, why it is providing null in request header origin

Comment: Your CORS configuration needs to be updated so that the server sends back an Access-Control-Allow-Headers response header that includes 'Content-Type' in its value.